# Does ARIN require ISPs ask for SSL key pairs before issuing an IP address?

Tags: ip-address, isp

I've just asked for a new IP address for an SSL website, and my ISP responded:

> Before we can assign the 1 Additional IP Address you requested for [server name], we
>   must first ask you to provide the SSL certificate and key pair for the
>   respective FQDN that it will be used for.
>
> Recently we have updated our address assignment policy to better
>   handle the global depletion of IPv4 addresses. One of the measures we
>   are taking is if customers are requesting additional IP addresses for
>   use of e-commerce/SSL-enabled sites, we ask that customers please
>   provide us with the SSL Cert and Key pair when making the request.
>   This is to ensure the SSL certificate and key pairs the customer
>   provides us with is/are indeed legitimate and do match. We have had
>   problems in the past with some customers either not using the IP
>   addresses assigned to them for SSL, or customers have provided us
>   fake, mismatching, or outdated SSL cert and key pairs.
>
> Please note that a wildcard SSL certificate will only allow you one
>   (1) additional IP Address.
>
> Once you provide us with the SSL Certificate and Key pair, we can begin
>   the process of assigning you the additional IP Address.
>
> We apologize for this inconvenience, but the restrictions placed on us
>   by ARIN (the entity which controls IP address assignment in North
>   America) are quite specific, and [ISP name] is obligated to comply.

As a PCI compliant company, I can't just go around handing out our private keys to anyone who asks. From a brief skim through [ARIN's policies](https://www.arin.net/policy/index.html) I can't see anything forcing ISPs to request private keys.

**1. Does ARIN require ISPs to specifically ask for certificate key pairs?**

**2. Is this policy unique to my ISP or is it now standard at all reputable providers?**

Comment: I don't have an answer here, but the responses from @Cyclops and KTC in [this prior question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/do-all-us-providers-refuse-issuing-a-separate-ipv4-address-for-a-separate-website) might provide some more background.

Answer (score 1):

> Does ARIN require ISPs to specifically ask for certificate key
>   pairs?

There is no legitimate need for anyone else to have access to your private key if you are managing your own server - you have every right to be skeptical of this "requirement" and you can be certain that it is *not* an ARIN mandate (see [ARIN Number Resource Policy Manual](https://www.arin.net/policy/nrpm.html#four23)).

> Is this policy unique to my ISP or is it now standard at all
>   reputable providers?

This is not the behavior of a reputable provider.